# How to set default time zone as UTC in php?

Tags: php, timezone

Best way to set default time zone in php.

Can i use .htaccess file to set the default time zone for a project or should i use php.ini file to set default time zone for my whole server?

Comment: Use `php.ini` to set it for the whole server. Then if any project needs custom time zone it can use that within its code

Comment: It will be good so set in php.ini , but remember it will be same for all projects hosted on that server if you edit php.ini.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write a single line in start of page

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends, I would reccomend using the same default timezone on the whole server + database etc... Keeps things simple in logs and while debugging time sensitive stuff :)

(In other words, use `php.ini`!)